# Setting multiple DOCKER_OPTS arguments

Tags: docker

If you want to pass an option to the Docker Engine at startup on Ubuntu, you can edit the `/etc/defaults/docker` file.

Here I'm setting the storage driver to `AUFS`:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=aufs"
```

However, if I pass more than one argument, Docker doesn't start. For example:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry=0.0.0.0:5000 --storage-driver=aufs"
```

Now Docker fails to start:

```
# service docker stop && service docker start
docker start/running, process 31569
# service docker status
docker stop/waiting
```

From `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Mar 11 14:55:30 myhost kernel: [ 2788.030270] init: docker main process (31253) terminated with status 1
Mar 11 14:55:30 myhost kernel: [ 2788.030279] init: docker main process ended, respawning
Mar 11 14:55:30 myhost kernel: [ 2788.085931] init: docker main process (31287) terminated with status 1
Mar 11 14:55:30 myhost kernel: [ 2788.085940] init: docker respawning too fast, stopped
```

Each argument works on its own, but if passed together the Docker service refuses to start. I am using `Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd` on `Ubuntu 14.04 3.13.0-74-generic`.

How can I pass more than one argument to `DOCKER_OPTS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments must be separated by `,`

This format works:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry=0.0.0.0:5000,--storage-driver=aufs"
```

Comment: I am running Docker on Ubuntu and using DOCKER_OPTS and it does not require commas between the arguments.  A few differences in my setup, I have Ubuntu 15.10, which uses Systemd and I'm using Docker version 1.9.1  I'm not sure what causes this difference.

Comment: Good point. I just tried on my docker-machine VM with `Linux dev 4.1.18-boot2docker` and it works with spaces there too.